# Visual studio 2008 confuration manager several builds

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2008, automation

I have Visual studio 2008 and in confuration manager I have several versions of my project: Demo,Standard,Full.

But when I change something in my project I want to rebuild all my versions of project.

How can I do this? (I think that solution should use .bat file for automatization, but settings should been taken from VS2008 .sln file)

Answer (score 0):

it works

```
vcbuild "myproj.sln" "Release-Demo|win32"
```